# How do you simplify the difference between functions of x in R with respect to a Calculus context?

Tags: r

First of all, this looks like a fair amount of Calculus, so I predict that it would get forwarded to Cross-Validated by someone who thinks that this is TL;DR. But I think this is a programming question, so here me out.

Imagine that I have the following functions in terms of x: f(x), g(x), h(x) ...

f(x) = 2x^2 + 4x - 30

g(x) = x^2 - x + 12

h(x) = f(x) - g(x) = (2x^2 + 4x - 30) - (x^2 - x + 12) = x^2 + 5*x - 42

Note: If I were to compute g(x) - f(x) here I would get a different polynomial, but I would get the same roots so it doesn't really matter because if I took the coefficients from g(x) - f(x), then polyroot() would return the same x-intercept intersection points as f(x) = g(x).

I am able to resolve h(x) = (2x^2 + 4x - 30) - (x^2 - x + 12), but I can't resolve it to x^2 + 5*x - 42 which is just a more simplified version of the same function of h(x). But I need it in this form to compute the intersections of these functions where I need the coefficients of the difference function. Then I would use the points of intersection to compute the difference integral over the greater function minus the smaller function over the range where the functions intersect, and this difference integral is simply the area between the functions.

So my goal is to compute the area between two intersecting functions.

My problem is that I want to automate the whole process, and I want to simply the h(x) difference function to 1*x^2 + 5*(x) - 42, where the coefficients of this polynomial function in increasing order are -42, 5, 1 in that order.

So let's just write the code:

> fx <- function(x){2*x^2 + 4*x - 30}
>
> gx <- function(x){1*x^2 - 1*x + 12}
>
> hx <- function(x){fx - gx} # doesn't work because I can't pass it to curve(hx)
>
> hx <- function(x){(2*x^2 + 4*x - 30) - (1*x^2 - 1*x + 12)} # works 
>   but it is not in the form that I want.

```
> hx
function(x){(2*x^2 + 4*x - 30) - (1*x^2 - 1*x + 12)}
<bytecode: 0x000000001c0bfc10>
```

Errors:

```
> curve(hx)

Error in expression(fx) - expression(gx) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

See this is why I need the coefficients.

```
> z <- polyroot(c(-42, 5, 1)) # polyroot functions give you the x-intercepts of a polynomial function. 
> z
[1]  4.446222-0i -9.446222+0i
```

Of course I could just compute "x^2 + 5*x - 42" on pen and paper, but they say that programmers always want to find the most efficient algorithmic process with the least amount of work.

Now I need to see which function is greater than the other, over the given range. Two ways visually or incrementally. (This is for the Calculus II part.)

> x = seq(from = -9.4, to = 4.4, by = 0.2)
>   fx_range = 2*x^2 + 4*x - 30

```
> table(fx_range >= gx_range)

FALSE 
   70 
> table(gx_range >= fx_range)

TRUE 
  70
```

It looks like the g(x) function is greater than or equal to the f(x) function over the range of the intersection points. So should evalulate the integral of g(x) - f(x) according to calculus. I was just doing f(x) - g(x) earlier for the polyroot function.

Area<sub>between curves</sub> = (from -9.446222 to 4.446222) ∫[g(x) - f(x)]dx

= (from -9.446222 to 4.446222) ∫[(x^2 - x + 12) - (2*x^2 + 4*x - 30)]

> gx_minus_fx = function(x){(x^2 - x + 12) - (2*x^2 + 4*x - 30)}
>
> Area = integrate(gx_minus_fx, lower = -9.446222, upper = 4.446222)
>
> Area 
>   446.8736 with absolute error < 5e-12 # This is exactly what I wanted to compute!

Now let's graphically check if I was supposed to subtract g(x) - f(x):

```
> curve(fx, main = "Functions with their Intersection Points", xlab = "x", ylab = "Functions of x", from = -9.446222, to = 4.446222)
> curve(gx, col = "red", add = TRUE)
> legend("topright", c("f(x) = 2x^2 + 4x - 30", "g(x) = x^2 - x + 12"), fill = c("black", "red"))
```

[image: Functions with Their Intersections]

Yeah, I did it right!

So again, what I would like help with is figuring out how I could simplify
h(x) = f(x) - g(x) to x^2 + 5*x - 42.
This appears to be an algebraic problem. I showed that I could do high-level Calculus 2 in R, and I would just like to know if there is a way that I can automate this whole process for the h(x) function.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Unless you typed the question wrong, the reason that `hx <- function(x){fx - gx}` does not work is that you left out x    You need `hx <- function(x){fx(x) - gx(x)}`

Comment: You say you want to automate this for other examples. How will you be given the functions f and g?  In your example, you hard-coded the coefficients. That is not scalable. Presumably,  you will be given the coefficients of the polynomials for the new examples. Just keep those coefficients and take the difference of them.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense!